# Ember does not call the rails backend

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, ember.js, ember-data

I'm working on a project with ember in front end and rails in back end. Rails server is running on 3000 port and ember on 4200 port. I have an ember model bugs and in my routes/index.js code,

```
this.store.findAll('bug')
```

and I'm getting the following error

```
GET http://localhost:4200/bugs 404 (Not Found)
```

Below is my adapter

```
# app/adapters/application.js

import ActiveModelAdapter from 'active-model-adapter';
import ENV from '../config/environment';

export default ActiveModelAdapter.extend({
  namespace: 'api/v1',
  host: ENV['serverURL']     // ENV['serverURL'] is http://localhost:3000
});
```

I do not see any request coming to the backend server. Let me know if you need any further information.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it makes the request to `http://localhost:4200/bugs` so probably `ENV['serverURL']` is *not* `http://localhost:3000`! Have you checked this with the debugger?

But what ember version are you using? `DS.ActiveModelAdapter` is not part of ember-data 2.5.2 as far as I know, but an extra [addon](https://github.com/ember-data/active-model-adapter).

Also have you configured your rails backend for CORS? I would recommend to use the `--proxy= http://localhost:3000` for your development and later use rails to provide your compiled ember app in production.

Comment: ENV['serverURL'] is localhost:3000. and I'm using ember-data 2.5.2, as you said i installed active-model-adapter and tried but still getting the same error. And my rails backend support CORS.

Comment: Hi Lux, my application behaves so strange. I have to change the filename 'adapaters/application.js' to 'adapaters/bug.js'. Now it's working good.

Comment: Hm, so you applied the wrong adapter. Did you may had a `adapter/bug.js` file that exports an adapter that does not inherit from your application adapter?